# How to scan QR code to link to different view controller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I was able to follow a QR reader tutorial but it can only scan the code and output the link or the text or the image name on a label. I want to be able to scan the code and have it send me to a different view controller on my iOS app. Ideally, the QR code is an account number and after scanning the QR code, a view controller of that specific account will open. Other QR codes will have other account numbers and will open a different account on the same style view controller.

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{


if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {

    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {


        [_lblStatus performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[metadataObj stringValue] waitUntilDone:NO];




        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        [_bbitemStart performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setTitle:) withObject:@"Start!" waitUntilDone:NO];

        _isReading = NO;
```

that is my code. I attempted making the QR code just simple text like "A123" and have it switch to a controller when the label = @"A123" but it does not work.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Describe the error messages, undesired behavior, or monitor explosions you observed.

Comment: I only get the label to display the URL or the text. I cannot get it to do anything with the URL or text is scans. For example, if the QR code is for nba.com, it will just display a label that says "nba.com". I tried making an if statement so that when the label = a certain text, it would switch controllers but it just keeps displaying the text on the same label.